# Cannot access the iframe style height and width and change it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm running into an issue where I can't seem to access my iframe style elements (width and height mostly). I'm obviously not doing something right. Hopefully someone could point me into the right direction. Any help or feedback is appreciated :)

**This is my main page (index.html):**
This page includes the iframe

```
<iframe class="myiFrame" src="iframes/iframe1.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**iframe1.html page:**
    This page includes a javascript file

```
<script src="../../../html/files/js/slider.js"></script>
```

**slider.js file**
In this .js file, I want to access the iframe style height and width

`document.getElementsByClassName("myiFrame");`

Also, in the console I get the error

**`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"`**

Comment: So, you want a script in the iframed page to modify the width and height of the iframe element that it is loaded in, in its parent frame?

Comment: Yup! Exactly :) Can this be done?

Comment: Does the console shows any error?

Comment: @NicoDiz - Thank you for the reply. If i'm doing it correctly (which I know I am not lol) I get the error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Css style width:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myiFrame")[0].style.width
```

real width:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myiFrame")[0].offsetWidth
```

using JQuery:

```
$(".myiFrame").css("width");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`, maybe for some reason you are trying to access to the iframe before it is loaded.

You can fire your function after the DOM is loaded. See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Example:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var myIFrame = document.querySelector(".myiFrame");
        console.log({ myIFrame });  // check also this console
        if (myIFrame) {
            // your code
        }
    });
</script>
```